# 2 NIC's with ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, nic

Good day all,

I have an ESXi server running in a Data Center. The server is connected to an HP Pro Curve 2810 switch on NIC 1.
I have a second NIC on the server which I want to connect to a second Pro Curve switch.

I would like the ESXi server to be setup, when NIC 1 fails (disconnected cable etc) it switches to NIC 2.

Is that possible? And if so how to set it up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You configure failover NICs for the vSwitch that you would like to be redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! :-)
I have a really easy setup: 1 vSwitch and all VM's are on that vSwitch.

I just add the 2nd NIC to the vSwitch and that's it? Or...

Comment: You add the second NIC and configure it as a standby, yes. It's fairly straightforward if you just want failover.

Comment: Ok, thanks again! I will have a look at it. Yes failover is what I want.

Comment: Can I just go with the default settings for NIC teaming and put the second NIC as standby?

Comment: Yes. One NIC will be active and the other NIC will be standby. You know that this is pretty thoroughly documented. Have you tried looking in the VMware knowledgebase?

Comment: I did check the KB. But I found a lot of articles about NIC teaming but not really about plane and simple redundancy. I do not need link aggregation I only want the second NIC to be used when NIC 1 fails.